# Return value in powershell script stored in string not utf8

Tags: powershell, script, utf-8

I'm trying to extract tables out of a pdf using tabula and powershell. When I enter the command directly in the powershell console, I get the expected result displayed (in utf8 with umlaut-symbols)

```
java -jar "./tabula-java/$tabulaVersion" --spreadsheet -a 114,53,180,556 "./table.pdf"
```

But when I put it in a string variable and then write to a file the umlaut symbols become gibberish

```
$text = java -jar "./tabula-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar" --spreadsheet -a 114,53,180,556 "./table.pdf"   
Set-Content -Path "./file.txt" -Value $text
```

Even if I print the variable in the console, the umlaut-symbols are not properly displayed

```
$text = java -jar "./tabula-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar" --spreadsheet -a 114,53,180,556 "./table.pdf"   
Write-Output $text
```

Is there a way to store it in a string variable (and therefore being able to manipulate the content) and write it to a file with keeping the utf8 (without BOM) encoding?

Using the approach from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5596984/1786528 does not work for me either

```
$Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($filepath, $text, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
```

<del>I don't get an error, but also no file is created or line added.</del>

### Update:

`[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines` creates a file (in UTF without BOM), I just used a relative path and did not set `[System.Environment]::CurrentDirectory = (Get-Location).Path`. But nonetheless are the umlaut-symbols not correct.

### Additional details

**case 1:** 
output directly in console, e.g.

```
java -jar "./tabula-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar" --spreadsheet "./table.pdf"
```

**case 2:** 
output stored in variable, then printed in console, e.g.

```
$text = java -jar "./tabula-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar" --spreadsheet "./table.pdf"   
Write-Output $text
```

**case 3:** 
output stored in variable but with `-D"file.encoding=UTF-8"`, then printed in console, e.g.

```
$text = java -D"file.encoding=UTF-8" -jar "./tabula-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar" --spreadsheet "./table.pdf"   
Write-Output $text
```

### Update:

`$OutputEncoding` = US-ASCII and 
`[System.Console]::OutputEncoding` = OEM United States (IBM437)

**case 4:** 
output directly in console (with changing `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding` beforehand), e.g.

```
[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)
java -jar "./tabula-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar" --spreadsheet "./table.pdf"
```

**case 5:** 
output stored in variable, then printed in console (with changing `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding` beforehand), e.g.

```
[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)
$text = java -jar "./tabula-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar" --spreadsheet "./table.pdf"   
Write-Output $text
```

This will result in this for umlaut symbols

```
pdf    case 1    case 2     case 3    case 4     case 5
 ä      ä         Σ          ├ñ        „          Ã¤
 ö      ö         ÷          ├╢        ”          Ã¶
 ü      ü         ⁿ          ├╝                  Ã¼
```

Comment: you could try `$text = java -jar "./tabula-java/$tabulaVersion" --spreadsheet -a 114,53,180,556 $filepath | out-file -FilePath "./file.txt" -Encoding UTF8` if it does not work, the output ist most likely already wrong

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. I also think that the culprit is at `$text = java ...` (see my update). But I do not understand why the response is displayed correctly when I just use `java ...` and as soon as I store it in a variable not anymore. It also creates a working file if I write the output directly with the tabula command (using `-o "./file.txt"`)

Comment: look at this answer on stack overflow - looks like you can specify UTF8 encoding already in `java ...` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733029/output-as-utf-8-encoding-in-java adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`should do the trick

Comment: This sounded promising, but I get this error message `Error: Could not find or load main class .encoding=UTF-8`. I tried to find more about `-Dfile`, but not very successfully

Comment: hmm i guess you have to wait for a java commandline pro. you should search for `java commandline output UTF8` or probably even `java tabula UTF8 encoding`. Can't help any further since I don't know too much about java (maybe readme.md in github helps)

Comment: Maybe this isn't related, but maybe it is: When working on a PS-script that features exiftool (which supports UTF), I had the same problem as you had (same thing with working console, same thing with non-working UTF-encoding). Sadly, the only (non-)solution I could come up with was to add the BOM. So what I want to say is that I wouldn't think that Java is the culprit here.

Comment: Please show some example (with more _umlauted_ as well as _common_ letters) of expected result and corresponding gibberish (for every given case).

Comment: Try `java -D"file.encoding=UTF-8" ...`.  You can also try setting the environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` to `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`.

Comment: With `java -D"file.encoding=UTF-8"`, there is no error anymore and I get a different output, but it's still not correct (file is UTF-16 LE). `ä` becomes `├ñ`, without `java -D"file.encoding=UTF-8"` it was `Σ`

Comment: There is a weird and perplexing difference between **case 1** and **case 2**. What is your `$OutputEncoding` and `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding`? What happens with `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)` just before calling `java …`/`$text = java …`?

Comment: `$OutputEncoding` = US-ASCII and `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding` = OEM United States (IBM437). I added the new cases to my post

Comment: Flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) occurrence: for instance, try `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines( $MyPath, 'äöü', [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]($False))`. Then, `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($MyPath, [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(437))` covers your _case 3_ (and  _case 5_ changing `437`  to `1252`) etc. Unfortunately, I don't know how to configure `java` output encoding…

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So the culprit is java, not Powershell?